# Order of inheritance in c#

Tags: c#, loops

I wanna know if suppose i have a base class A  that inherit a Interface Say I and another class say B then Is there any difference between

```
Class A : I,B
{
  // Function and Members
}
```

and

```
Class A : B,I
{
   // Function and Members
}
```

Comment: base class should come first before the interface. because you can only inherit one base class.

Comment: @JW. could u please elaborate more on this !!!

Comment: As far as I know, C# does not support multiple inheritance directly like you are trying to express here

Comment: Have you actually tried to use any of these versions?

Comment: Guessing **I** nterface **B** ase class

Comment: @JohnGathogo I knew it, Here I is a Interface !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *have* to specify the class first.

From section 10.1.4 of the C# 4 specification:

> A class declaration may include a class-base specification, which defines the direct base class of the class and the interfaces directly implemented by the class.
>
> ```
> class-base:
>    : class-type
>    : interface-type-list
>    : class-type , interface-type-list
> ```

Note the absence of an `interface-type-list , class-type` option.

Answer (score 2):

You should always put the base class first. 
in C# you can only inherit one class, but many interfaces:

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass, IInterface1, IInterface2
{
}
```

The order of interfaces does not matter

```
public class MyClass : BaseClass, IInterface2, IInterface1
{
}
```